# Style.Add distorts string, replaces spaces with "%20"

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

```
string backgroundImage = "url(http://path/alert.png), linear-gradient(-45deg, #8c7814 0%, #a99118 100%)"
panel.Style.Add("background-image", backgroundImage);
```

And now, in the Immediate window, I do this:

```
panel.Style.Value
```

Resulting in:

```
"background-image:url(http://path/alert.png),%20linear-gradient(-45deg,%20#8c7814%200%,%20#a99118%20100%);"
```

What gives?

Comment: Out of interest does it do the same with other styles? Perhaps the framework is seeing the `background-image` style, assuming a url and escaping the value? Have you tried with the `background` style?

Comment: @NathanLee: Adding it where? I tried a backgroundImage.Replace(" ", "&nbsp"); but that resulted in the same.

Comment: @DaveParsons aha! background-size does in fact NOT have this problem. I will try with the background style. Can I use that to accomplish the same as I'm doing now (background-image, background-position, background-size, background-repeat)?

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson: There's one way to find out.

Comment: Yeah, sorry :) I have switched to background now and it's almost where I want to be it. I'll take it from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to add those styles in a css class

```
.newClass
{
    background-image:url(http://path/alert.png);
}
```

and then

```
panel.CssClass="newClass";
string backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(-45deg, #8c7814 0%, #a99118 100%)";
panel.Style.Add("background", backgroundImage);
```

Comment: But the values are created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

As per DaveParson's suggestion, switching to the "background" shorthand was the key to fixing this.